# New to proofs and would like your shared experience

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, proof-theory

An integer $a$ is *"happy"* if it can be written on the form $a=6k+3$ for some integer k. Let $y$ denote an integer. Prove that $y$ is *"happy"* if and only if $y^2$ is *"happy"*.

**My proof:**

Assume that $y$ is a *happy* integer, that is $y=6k+3$. Then we have $y^2=(6k+3)^2=36k^2+36k+6+3=$ $\color{blue}{\textrm{6($6k^2+6k+1$)}}$$+3$ which is the same as $\color{blue}{\textrm{6$m$}}$$+3$ for some integer $m$. Thus we have that if $y$ is *happy* then so is $y^2$.

Next we show that there exist no integers that yield a *happy* square other than those integers who can be expressed on the form $6k+3$.

$1. (6k+1)^2=36 k^2 + 12 k + 1 \neq6m+3$

$2. (6k+2)^2=36 k^2 + 24 k + 4\neq6m+3$

$3. (6k+4)^2=36 k^2 + 48 k + 16 \neq6m+3$

$4. (6k+5)^2=36 k^2 + 60 k + 25 \neq6m+3$

We find that the only way of achieving a *happy* integer by squaring is by squaring an already *happy* integer. Since squaring a number is a reversable operation, if we take the square root of a *happy* number and it is still an integer, then it can only have mapped onto a *happy number* $6k+3$. Hence we have shown that iff a square is *happy* then so is its square root (if it is still an integer). ■

**My questions:**

First of all if it is correct? Furthermore, I feel like the proof have unnecessary steps somehow and would very much like to shorten it, how can one do that?. Also, I have just started to read about how to prove/present the idea of a proof by oneself - was there anything you wished you knew regarding proofs during these early stages that I am going through that might be useful to know before taking on more advance excersices?

Comment: Your argument looks good but, as you say, there's some unnecessary work in it.  You can save yourself time by noting that $3\nmid y\iff 3\nmid y^2$ (this is true for any prime, not just $3$).  Thus you really only need to consider $6k$ and $6k+3$.

Comment: Note:  you appear to omit the case $y=6k$.  Of course this case is easily handled, but it should be mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using prime factorization, as follows. (Just noted this is basically what is suggested in [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu)'s comment.)

---

$\Rightarrow$

If $$y = 6k+3 = 3(2k+1),$$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$, then $y$ must be of the form 
$$ y = 3\prod_i p_i^{j_i},$$
with $p_i$ odd primes.

So

$$y^2 = 3\cdot\underbrace{\left(3 \prod_i p_i^{2j_i}\right)}_{\small\mbox{odd}},$$

and thus also $y^2$ is of the form

$$y^2 = 3(2h+1),$$
for some $h \in \Bbb Z$

---

$\Leftarrow$

Conversely, if $z$ is the square of some integer $y$ and

$$z = 3(2k+1),$$
then it must be

$$z = 3\left(3\prod_i p_i^{2j_i}\right),$$
with $p_i$ odd primes, because, the product is odd.

Thus

$$y = 3 \underbrace{\prod_i p_i^{j_i}}_{\small{\mbox{odd}}}.$$
Therefore it must be
$$y= 3(2h +1),$$
for some $h\in\Bbb Z$.